# Cursor not working in Edge & IE on margin-right with SVG

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

As the title describes I'm having a issue with a cursor. 
What I have done is I placed  `a` link where it can download some pdf file. All hover effects are working except the pointer. When hovering over the svg I see a cursor: pointer (this is good) but when i'm at the point where the margin right start it is back to the cursor type: default.

Removing the margin will help but then the text is straight next two the SVG and that is something I don't want.

Checked it on the following browser:

- Chrome v. 54 : no problem
- Firefox v. 49.01 : no problem
- IE v. 11.6 : problem
- Edge v. 25 : problem

Below the code for some context and the problem button. I'm doing something wrong but cannot figure it out.  :)

[image: button pdf] [image: problem button pdf]

**CSS**

```
.btn {
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  color: #45443d;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.btn svg {
  fill: #45443d;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: #f78400;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.btn--pdf:hover {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: #16915b;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.btn--pdf:hover svg {
  fill: white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn--pdf">
    <svg class="btn__icon">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-pdf"></use>
    </svg>
    PDF
</a>
```

**UPDATE**

Forgot the icon class.

```
.btn__icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUwuXqKsv4CGvMHRl2Ae?p=preview)

Comment: Your `a` has no `href` attribute, and therefor it doesn’t get a pointer cursor by default from the browser stylesheet.

Comment: This is not in the code but this is done by angular :)